# Structuring and Designing SQL Database for List of Items Containing More Lists of Items

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, relational-database

I have collected a bunch of crafts and DIY instructionals over the years. Each has a list of instructions and a list of materials needed.

I want to store these in a database, but as I have limited experience I'm questioning the correct/proper way to structure and Design the database for SQL.

Initially I was going to put everything in one table, so each record would represent a project, and then there would be one field for the instructions and one field materials. Each set of instructions would go into one value, perhaps separated by some character or symbol.

However, I'm wondering if it's better to separate the instructions and materials into their own tables (a table for each instruction set for each project). But with this method, there would have to be hundreds of tables if I create a table for each set of instructions for each project.

The third option would be to put ALL the instructions for each project into one table, then give them an id for the corresponding project, and an id for the order they should appear. But this would mean possible duplicates, especially in the materials table (hammer, for instance would appear multiple times, but would have separate ids referring to separate projects). I also worry about the table being too big with thousands of entries.

The fourth option would be to have one table, but add an excessive number of fields for instructions and materials, and only use the ones needed for each project (for example 100 "materials" fields, but perhaps one project only uses 10 and the other 99), but this does not seem proper, and could lead to trouble later on.

Is there a standard way to go about solving this problem, structuring a database for a list of things, which each reference another list of things?

Comment: there is a standard way and that standard way is described in any tutorial on 'database normalization'

Comment: Consider how to describe your state: project P step N is I. project P uses M. PS It turns out that there is no problem per se with multiple appearances of a subrow of values, but there can be a problem with the same statement being made by multiple subrows of values.

Comment: Thanks, but even after "normalization," I am still stuck with the first 3 options, which can each be done with normalization, I believe. I guess we can rule out option 2, since it's not an optimum use of time/space? That still leaves having tables with thousands of instructions/materials as individual attributes, or trying to figure out how to separate/distinguish multiple materials/steps in one attribute?

Comment: Your problem statement makes it sound like you have never mastered the basics of database design.  The relationship between materials and projects is many-to-many.  Do you know how to design for this case?

Comment: If you will not be looking up items in SQL, toss the lists into JSON.

Comment: My issue is whether the relationship between materials and projects is many to many or one to many. Each material can refer to one project. Each project can refer to multiple materials. Same with instructions. Also, this would have to be a db because i would like to use it with an application, and add to it or edit it.